# How to add a number of rows determined by a reference cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel spreadsheet with a few hundred files. Within each file is several images. I need each image to have a new row inserted under the "parent" file row. I have code that will insert the correct number of rows, but it won't go to the next cell and none of the offset's I change are fixing it.

```
Sub CB3262014()
Dim i As Integer, n As Integer, m As Long, currentCell As Range
Set currentCell = ActiveCell
Do While Not IsEmpty(currentCell)
n = currentCell.Value
m = currentCell.Row
If n > 0 Then
Rows(m + 1 & ":" & m + n).Insert
Set currentCell = currentCell.Offset(n + 1, 0)
Else
Set currentCell = currentCell.Offset(1, 0)
End If
Loop
End Sub
```

I'm also struggling with how to get it to jump down/skip two rows each time. The way my data set is set up, there's two rows - then the row with the parent file and the reference number for how many additional rows to add.

Here's a sample from the spreadsheet and how I would like it to be. I will fill in file names, I just put them there so it's easier to see what's happening.

Current Spreadsheet [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRdXE.png

Goal Spreadsheet [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6evMO.png

Comment: Can you explain the part: "The way my data set is set up, there's two rows - then the row with the parent file and the reference number for how many additional rows to add." - Maybe update your question with how the data looks, so we can give you the final solution you're looking for....

Comment: you aren't resetting n to be 0 at the end of each loop

Comment: a cheap way of avoiding the issue is to set the currentcell to offset(1,0) before the insert operation then insert the rows on currentcell.offset(-1,0) :D

Comment: I've added links to the images. I can't attach images directly.

Comment: Which lines would that be on @Cor_Blimey ?

Comment: @crabab11 to run this you are selecting one of the cells in column E then running it? Do the cells without values in column E have an empty string in them or are they blanks? If blanks then it won't go to the next cell because it is stopping running due to `Do While Not IsEmpty`. Try `Do Until currentCell is Range("C100000").End(xlUp)` or something instead.

Comment: @crabab11 ok ill post it as an answer - please mark it as the answer then ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By inspection of the attached images, it seems the loop is looping down rows with blanks in. The loop therefore stops immediately on encountering the first blank due to:

`Do While Not IsEmpty(currentCell)`

So, replace that with `Do Until currentCell is Range("C100000").End(xlUp)` and the loop should continue as expected. A minor performance improvement would be to cache that cell to save evaluating it each loop such as:

```
Dim lastCell As Range
Set lastCell = Range("C100000").End(xlUp)
Do Until currentCell is lastCell
...etc
Loop
```